# Maximizing image quality from image data

Tags: image-processing, esp32

My project uses an OV2640 sensor on an ESP32-CAM board.

I need to get the raw RGGB data from the sensor.
However, due to Omnivision unwiligness to provide the datasheet for this sensor (the one online is only a partial version). I can only get the data in Jpeg (relatively high compression), YUV422 or RGB565.

In all these cases, the original 10 bit per pixel bayer data has been "tinkered" with and degraded to produce data that I get.

In my tests, for a 320*240 image, in jpeg, the compressed image is 10KB, in YUV it is of course 75KB and twice this (150KB) in RGB565 mode...

Now, the problem is that these all represent tinkered versions of the sensor original bayer (RGGB) data (at 8 bit per pixels).

What is the best way to recover (as closely as possible) the original RGGB values for each of the pixels?

Thanks,
Cyrille

Comment: there is absolutely no point in deriving anything looking like original sensor data from already debayered, quantized (5-6 bits), and compressed (!) data. the degradation cannot be undone.